# How can I install Firebase in Expo React native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm trying to install Firebase in Expo.

On the Expo document, they recommend using this library
`react-native-firebase`.

What do I need to do after running this command?

```
npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app
```

Comment: The question is, what are you going to do with Firebase?

Comment: I want to use Firestore database and Storage for small project

Answer (score 5):

First of all, if you are working with an expo you should be using the below command to install Firebase for your expo

```
expo install firebase
```

After that, you need to visit your Firebase Console and get the API key and other identifiers from there into a new file and store that information such as

```
const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: 'api-key',
   authDomain: 'project-id.firebaseapp.com',
   databaseURL: 'https://project-id.firebaseio.com',
   projectId: 'project-id',
   storageBucket: 'project-id.appspot.com',
   messagingSenderId: 'sender-id',
   appId: 'app-id',
   measurementId: 'G-measurement-id',
};
```

After this, you are good to go and start working with Firebase

You can refer to [Expo Firebase Documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/) for a more detailed understanding.

Feel free to ask anything more

Comment: This library allows other functions that the common SDK web doesn't allow @react-native-firebase/app. So, What I mean, is that he was referring to how to install that library.

Answer (score 1):

Install firebase in expo-project via `expo install firebase` instead of `npm`.

If you want to use `firestore` use the `JS sdk`, and get the firestore like this:

```
const db = initializeFirestore(app,{useFetchStreams :false}as any)
```

After that use it normally as you would use. `GoogleSignIn` doesn't work on mobile devices if you are using `JS sdk` or atleast of me it didn't work.